# How to burn an iso image from the command line

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, burning

Is that possible to get an alternative to the command `dd` to burn an `iso` image including some options:

**Detect** the burning device , **Burn** an `iso`  image and **eject** the CD from the command line?

Comment: Which Linux distrubution?

Comment: @EightBitTony Debian jessie , KDE environnement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In KDE the reference CD burning software is [K3b](http://www.k3b.org/), which is packaged in Debian as [`k3b`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/k3b).

On the command-line you'd probably use [cdrkit](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/cdrkit) (the main package is called `wodim`).

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Kitt and @EightBitTony , using the command `wodim` we can detect , burn and eject the disk by adding the following options `--devices` and `-eject`

Answer (score 3):

For basic burning, Debian has at least the following tools,

`wodim -v dev=/dev/sr0 -dao /home/user/file.iso`

`cdrskin -v dev=/dev/sr0 -dao /home/user/file.iso`

`xorriso -as cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 -dao /home/user/file.iso`

I don't know if they support all the features you require.  You can get more details from [the Debian site](https://wiki.debian.org/BurnCd).